# I cant use open() in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

i use amd and windows.

im coding a way to automate a discord bot to win, because me and some friends are competing against each other, my problem is that i want the program to log each time it does something, but i cant write into my file here is the code.

```
import pyautogui
from threading import Thread
import threading
import datetime
from time import sleep

now = datetime.datetime.now()
date="[" + str(now.year) + "/" + str(now.month) + "/" + \
       str(now.day) + "/" + str(now.hour) + "/" + \
       str(now.minute) + "/" + str(now.second) + "]"

global f
f=open("log.txt", "a")
f.write("started")



def hunt():
    global f
    pyautogui.typewrite("owo h")
    pyautogui.press("enter")
    print("Owo acaba de cazar")
    f.write(date + "Succesfuly hunted")
    threading.Timer(31.0, hunt).start()




def pray ():
    global f
    pyautogui.typewrite("owo pray")
    pyautogui.press("enter")
    print("Owo acaba de hacer pray")
    f.write(date +"Succesfuly prayed")
    threading.Timer(300.0, pray).start()


f.write("popo")
Thread(target = hunt).start()
sleep(1)
Thread(target = pray).start()
```

Comment: Please provide more detail about what is and isn't working.  What does the file output look like now?  Are you getting any output in the file?

Comment: What _specifically_ happens? Does the `open` call succeed, or throw, and if it throws what is the error message?

Comment: the scripts doesnt gets an exceptions, the file is in blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to close your file at the end of your script `f.close()`.
Strings will be written after the file is closed.

An alternative would be `with open(...)`:

```
with open('log.txt', 'a') as file:
    file.write('text\n')
```

Comment: now it only writes "started" but it does not log the other things

Answer (score 0):

If you use 'open' command you must use close it after getting the work done.
For examle:

```
f = open('file.txt', "a")
f.write("something")
f.close()  # For to save all changes.
```

Answer (score -1):

You didn't `.flush()` the file,which means your `.write()` calls(which write to a buffer) *stay* in the buffer and doesn't write to the disk.

So you'll need a `.flush()` call after *every* `.write()` call to write your changes to the disk right away.

(Also,you don't need a `global f` if you're *already* in the global scope.)

Comment: the script doesnt crash, it works but inside the .txt file there arent any info, and the .txt file is in the folder

Comment: You shouldn't be guessing. Use comments to ask for clarification

Comment: Thx,edited it to reflact the infomation in the comments.